# How to set the default Preferred Language

Tags: language

I think i must be missing something.

When I go to Option Groups /civicrm/admin/options?reset=1

and choose Language

/civicrm/admin/options?gid=75&reset=1

i see no value listed as Default, and no option when I click 'edit' on an option to set it as Default, yet if i look in the DB for values where option_group_id = 75 it shows en_US as default.

I set this to the desired value but where I am being blind in terms of doing this via the UI?

Comment: I have the same problem trying to set UK english. If anybody has an answer please let us know.

Comment: my sense is this is a bug/new requirement and someone needs to offer a patch. if you want us to look in to this I would be happy to offer 50% discount since it hit us too though clearly didn't cause enough of an itch at the time for us to scratch it.

Answer (score 1):

We can set default language in localization settings - `/civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1`

[image]

But, if I change that, the default value in the `options_value` table doesn't change, so not sure if it meets your requirement.

Comment: i think that is more the language setting for the interface, not the 'preferred language' of the contact.

Comment: and i don't see why i should need to download a 'translation' purely to avoid all the contacts being tagged as 'preferred language = en_US' because I assure you, it is not the preferred language in much of the world.